# Check if activity that used intent still alive

Tags: android, android-intent

I have two activities: `MainActivity` and `EventActivity`.

Whenever I open my app (in `MainActivity` by default) and it has a certain flag in `SharedPreferences`, it intents to `EventActivity` and finishes itself. Otherwise, it only intents.

In `EventActivity` I have a button that, when clicked, calls `finish()` and goes back to `EventActivity`.

The problem is, when I re-open my application, it will finish the `MainActivity` and, when I press my custom back button, it will close the app (because the intent handle has finished).

How do I check if `MainActivity` didn't used `finish()`?

If I can do that, checking if it is finished I can intent to it.

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. What do you mean by _"In `EventActivity` I have a button that, when clicked, calls `finish()` and goes back to `EventActivity`."_ Do you mean that it calls `finish()` and then goes back to `MainActivity`? If so, how does it go back to `MainActivity`? Does it call `startActivity()` to return to `MainActivity`?

Comment: You should probably post some code to make this more clear.

Comment: `MainActivity` is parent of `EventActivity` ok? When I launch the app (in MainActivity), I can intent to `EventActivity` and go back, right?
If I am at `EventActivity` and force close my app, when I open it again, it will start in `EventActivity`, because when I first executed an intent to `EventActivity`, I saved a flag in session. Now, when I try to press the `back button`, my app closes (because I don't have any other activity in the stack). Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override the `onDestroy` method of `MainActivity` in that set a `public` `static` `Boolean` field of `MainActivity`. In that method set that `public` `static` field as `true`. Check for its value in `EventActivity` before you finish it i.e. when you are coming back from `EventActivity` to `MainActivity`. And fire an intent to start `MainActivity` from `EventActivity` if it's value is `true`. And set it's value as `false` in `onCreate` of `MainActivity`.

As follows:

In MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public static boolean isMainActivityDestroyed = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        isMainActivityDestroyed = false;
        .
        .
        .//Do something here
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        isMainActivityDestroyed = true;
        .
        .
        .//Do something here
    }
}
```

In EventActivity.java

```
 public class EventActivity extends Activity {
      .
      .
      .//Some methods

      //Method which finishes EventActivity & starts MainActivity if destroyed
      public void buttonOnClick()
      {
            if(MainActivity.isMainActivityDestroyed)
            {
                Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
      }
 }
```

If `isMainActivityDestroyed` becomes true then it is an indication that `MainActivity` used `finish()`.

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own `Application` class extending `Application` and launch the needed activity from your Application's `onCreate`. In manifest you would then remove the default intent filter for your MainActivity.

Comment: This can't work. If you don't have a launch activity (ACTION_MAIN and CATEGORY_DEFAULT) then the application won't show up on the list of installed applications and the user won't be able to launch it at all!

Comment: Solved creating a static singleton class that holds the last activity before the current has launched.